# ASP.net Linq getting logged in user to filter a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I am using sqlMembershipProvider and I tried to get at the user object to filter a linq query. But i cant seem to find the UserID in this object.

here's my code:

```
var query =  (from b in db.Builders where b.UserID==b.UserID????ID select b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

the user is associated with the request, so you can pull the username from there

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

If you can reference the current context without using the static gateway HttpContext.Current, that would be event better.